# DICOM C-ECHO verification with ClearCanvas SDK

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

I am using ClearCanvas sdk to c-echo verifiy a remote dicom entity but the result I am always getting is 'Failed'. It seems that it is not even associating with the remote entity. below is my code to do this in vb.net. Am I doing it right?

```
Dim hostname As String = "RemoteHost"       
Dim ae As String = "RemoteAETitle"       
Dim port As Integer = "RemotePort"      
Dim lhost As String = "LocalAETitle" 

Dim checkremote = New VerificationScu()

Dim result As VerificationResult = checkremote.Verify(lhost, ae, hostname, port)

    If result = VerificationResult.Success Then
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString)

    End If
    checkremote.Join(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the API correctly, this should verify the connection.  Have you taken a look at any log messages generated?  This would help identify the problem.

Comment: The log doesn't contain anything regarding this verification. It seems that the request did not reach the remote dicom entity, it behaves the same even when this application is executed locally on the same machine (remote dicom entity).

Comment: @BhaskarAmatya, do you have a Logging.config setup to generate a log file?  It seems like if there is an error there would for sure be some sort of error log generated describing the problem, especially if it was related to a network communication issue.  The only reason there may not be a log would be if the SCP side just rejected the association.